# Как осуществить добавление товаров в корзину с помощью сессии?

Tags: php, сессия

Есть вывод товаров из БД, как сделать добавление товаров(идентификатор, фильтрация и цена) в корзину( на другую страницу) с помощью сессии?
этот вариант выдает соответсвующие данные у каждого товара, а на другой странице только последнего товара из БД.

```html
<?php
  session_start();

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `table_products`";
   $result = $link->query($sql); 
   // В цикле перебираем все записи таблицы и выводим их
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
   {
      ?>
  <div class="items">
    <img class="img-logo" src=< ?php echo 'css/img/sorts/'.$row[ 'img_logo']; ?> >

    <div class="price">
      <?php echo ''.$row['price'].' р.' ;?>
    </div>

    <div class="alc-must">
      <?php echo 'алк. '.$row['alcohol']. '% / Экстр. сусла ' .$row['must'].'%'; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="count">


      <div class="minus">
        -
      </div>
      <div class="number">
        0.5 л.
      </div>
      <div class="plus">
        +
      </div>
    </div>


    <?php  
      $_SESSION['id']= $row['id'];
      $_SESSION['price']= $row['price'];
      $_SESSION['filtration']= $row['filtration'];


      echo $_SESSION['id'];
      echo $_SESSION['price'];
      echo $_SESSION['filtration'];

      ?>

    </form>
  </div>


  <?php
   };
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно прочёл Ваш код то:
Вот это вот лишнее

```
<?php  
    $_SESSION['id']= $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['price']= $row['price'];
    $_SESSION['filtration']= $row['filtration'];


    echo $_SESSION['id'];
    echo $_SESSION['price'];
    echo $_SESSION['filtration'];
?>
```

Сделайте отдельный скрипт назовём его to_cart.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (!$_POST) die("no");
    $type_to = $_POST['type']; // add/sub/get
    if ($type_to == "get") die(json_encode($_SESSION['items']));
    $item_id = $_POST['item_id'];
    if (!$item_id) die("no");
    if ($type_to == "add") {
        $_SESSION['items'][$item_id]['price'] = $_POST['price'];
        $_SESSION['items'][$item_id]['filtration'] = $_POST['filtration'];
    } elseif ($type_to == "sub") unset($_SESSION['items'][$item_id]);
    die(json_encode($_SESSION['items']));
?>
```

Страница с товаром(примерная)

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="item-img">
        <img src="css/img/sorts<?=$row['img_logo']?>" />
    </div>
    <div class="item-title">
        <span class="item_id hide"><?=$row['id']?></span>
        <span class="title"><?=$row['id']?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item-price">
        <span class="price">
            <?=$row['price'];?>
        </span>
        руб.
    </div>
    <div class="item-option">
        <div class="item-option-count">
            <div class="sub">-</div>
            <div class="count">1</div>
            <div class="add">+</div>
        </div>
        ***
    </div>
    <button class="js-item" data-action="add">Добавить</button>
    <button class="js-item" data-action="sub">Убрать</button>
</div>
```

Далее на примере jQ скрипт который будет добавлять товары на страницу

```
var items = {};
$("js-item").on("click", function() {
    var form_data = new FormData;
    type = $(this).data("action");
    item_id = $(this).parent().find('.item_id').text();
    price = $(this).parent().find('.price').text();
    filtration = $(this).parent().find('.filtration').text();

    form_data.append("type", type);
    form_data.append("item_id", item_id);
    form_data.append("price ", price );
    form_data.append("filtration ", filtration );
    $.ajax({
        url: 'to_cart.php',
        async: false,
        data: form_data,
        type: 'post',
        success: function(msg) {
            if (msg != "no") {
                items = JSON.parse(msg);
                cart_update(items);
            }
        }
    });
});

function cart_update(items) {
    // Здесь работа с элементами корзины
}
```

Что бы получить список товаров у этого же скрипта

```
form_data = new FormData;
form_data.append("type", "get");
$.ajax({
    url: 'to_cart.php',
    async: false,
    data: form_data,
    type: 'post',
    success: function(msg) {
        if (msg != "no") {
            items = JSON.parse(msg);
            cart_update(items);
        }
    }
});
```

Как то так